# WordPress : Look up a category link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to get the link of a class of the page in WordPress.

```
http://localhost:8888/Scriptura/ScripturaForWordpress/category/a-category/
```

I tried this, but without success:

```
get_category_link( is_category() );
```

How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, but WordPress bothered me on this one, so I adopted a workaround:

```
$uri = '//' .$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]; // Alternative to get_permalink() does not work in all situations. In real life this variable is global.

$arrayHttp = [ 'http://', 'https://' ]; // Here it's not very nice, is to prepare the str_replace that follows ...
$testLink = ( $tabUri == $uri );
foreach ( ( array ) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $tabUri = $menu_item->url; // It retrieves the URL of the tab
            $tabUri = str_replace( $arrayHttp, '//', $tabUri ); // Treatment allows for comparison with the variable $url. If you have a solution for dealing with HyperText Transfer Protocol in a more elegant way, I'm interested ...
            // Following the foreach...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_category_link()` needs `category_id` as parametar. You can say like :

`get_category_link(get_cat_ID( $cat_name ));`